# Some submit options not taking effect after submitting form

Tags: 2007, forms-services

My form is successfully submitting to the Form library I have setup, but no success and failure messages are being displayed. In addition, despite the "after submit" action set to Create a new, blank form", the submitted form is displayed with its data.

- This form is created from scratch
- I checked for javascript errors in the console but there are none.
- The form is opened through the new button on the form library.
- Other forms on different sites do work as intended

What other factors could be the cause of this situation?

Screenshots of the submit options and the rules applying to the submit button:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyXUw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the "After submit" setting of "Create a new blank form" only means that, after submitting the form currently being filled up (with all it's data), InfoPath will pop a new blank form so users can continue entering forms. It doesn't clear the current form.

Are you saying that just opening the form blank and clicking submit, when you re-open it it has some values in it? If that's the case, is there anything on the SharePoint side like a custom workflow that would put values into promoted columns in the list?

Comment: No new blank form is shown and no javascript alert is shown either, I'm still seeing the form as if I haven't pressed the submit button despite the options set. (a form did get submitted and added to the form library). Screencast: http://screencast.com/t/rxivbY5as

So users can't continue filling forms and they won't even know the form was submitted unless I use conditional formatting, and a status field that gets set on submit, to display a message myself.